# Why some GeoProjections show just half of Chukotka region (Russian map)

Tags: bugs, curated-data, geography, entity

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

I've moved to **V.10.4** and proceed with Russian map (the aim is to geoplot regional distributions of some values). Notice most eastern Russian region - **Chukotka**. Chukotka, unlike other entities, comprises of two data pieces. Now my concern is [`GeoProjection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoProjection.html). Some of them reflect both parts, but others - just western half.

Sample of popular `GeoProjection`s to try.

```
list = {"Albers", "Bonne", "Equirectangular", "LambertAzimuthal", "Mercator",
   "Mollweide", "Orthographic", "Robinson", "Sinusoidal", "WinkelTripel"}
```

I've taken just two - `{"LambertAzimuthal", "Albers"}` to get:
[image]

Code to try with more `GeoProjection`s:

```
GeoListPlot[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Chukotka", "Russia"}], 
   GeoProjection -> #, ImageSize -> 200] & /@list
```

The **question** is 'why'? Is there a kind of regularity backed in `GeoProjection` specifics or just a bug also?

Comment: Added the bugs tag per note I added below.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is how the Albers projection method is supposed to work.

Albers bifurcates the world. So when you look at the map, you examine one side of the bifurcation, because of the location of Chukotka.

Modifying the `GeoGraphics` to zoom out using,

```
GeoRange-> "World"
```

We see that the location is visible in both instances

LambertAzimuthal:

[image: num1]

Albers (both sides visible):
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection

Comment: in `GeoListPlot[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Chukotka", "Russia"}], GeoProjection -> #, ImageSize -> 200, GeoRange -> "World"] & /@ list` almost all of projections make both sides visible. Take an example of `Mercator`...

Comment: Also, adding the option `GeoCenter -> Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Chukotka", "Russia"}]` shifts the split to 180 degrees from Chukotka, but it is still split ... Adding the bugs tag.